# BASH: �ls: command not found when typing 'ñ' by mistake

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line

When I erroneously type 'ñ' (expecting to type any command) and then remove it and type the correct letter, the output returns the command with a special character attached `�`, obviously the shell don't recognize the command and I must re-type it being careful not to type again the 'ñ' character.

e.g.

```
Wrong typing       @tachomi:~$ ñs
Correct typing     @tachomi:~$ ls
Output             �ls: command not found
```

- Why is this happening since I removed the wrong character?
- How can I solve this?

What I think is that this kind of characters `ñ , '` etc are not compatible with the shell being this the reason that the "memory" keeps something that it doesn't recognize, but I want to be sure why is this happening.

**I'm using bash shell**

Comment: When I type that in, bash tells me: `bash: $'\303\261s': command not found`, but `ls` continues to work normally. You might want to experiment with the builtin `hash` command: `hash -l`  and `hash -r`

Comment: Does not happen here... probably depend some strange LANG settings. In UTF-8 `ñ` is a two-bytes char, so you must have the terminal ignoring it. Which terminal are you using? How is LANG set?

Comment: @Rmano I'm using bash shell, how can I know the configured LANG?

Comment: <guessing> ñ is two bytes character and your backspace character for some reason deletes only one of them </guessing>

Comment: Bash, yes; but which terminal (`xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, whatever, there are a lot of them). To see LANG, type `locale -v` in your shell. Moreover, knowing the exact version of your OS would help.

Comment: @Rmano Is xterm, LANG=en_US

Comment: @jimmij That makes sense why, when the ñ is at the beginning of the command line and I remove it, the backspace is able to remove like "an other field", how can I fix this?

Comment: Tried it here on `xterm` and `gnome-terminal` and it works as expected, ([BackSpace] wipes ñ) but my lang is `en_GB.UTF-8`, so if you can reproduce this, could you test this by pressing [BackSpace] twice?  Once for the first byte of the unicode character and once for the second???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to all help, I could find out how to fix this.

The main issue is due to the UTF-8 encoding, the server didn't have it configured as said in comments.

**Quoting comments:**

[@Rmano]: *In `UTF-8`, `ñ` is a **two-bytes** char*

[@jimmij]: *backspace character for some reason deletes only one of them*

[@aecolley]: *Try setting the environment variable `LANG` to `C.UTF-8`*

This is fixed as follows:

```
Find your current LANG    $ locale -v | grep 'LANG='
Output                    LANG=en_US
Change                    $ sudo LANG=en_US.UTF-8
or
Change                    $ sudo vim /etc/default/locale
Edit                      ~LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Restart your terminal session.

Answer (score 7):

You have a terminal (or terminal emulator) which understands multibyte encodings (probably UTF-8), but a shell which doesn't. Try setting the environment variable `LANG` to `C.UTF-8`. Or run `locale -a` to find another likely value to try.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following line of code:

```
if [[$(locale -v | grep 'LANG=') != *.UTF-8]]; then sudo $(locale -v | grep 'LANG=').UTF-8; fi
```

If the character code is not already `UTF-8`, it will set the character code to the `UTF-8` version of the current character code. This way, the shell will understand UTF-8 characters, and will backspace them properly.